# Android Activity::onCreate called before Application.onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity

In some cases I can see that Activity.onCreate is called before the Appication object gets created (before Application.onCreate is called). Is that ever possible?

Comment: It shouldn't be. How are you determining that this is happening?

Comment: Can you share your manifest file

Comment: Would you mind sharing the cases you are talking about?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue right now. It was working fine before but from today I'm getting this error

Comment: I also have same issue

Answer (score 1):

May be you forgot to add your application class in manifest file.

Place your application class in `AndroidManifest.xml` class under `<application>` tag.

i.e.,

```
<application
    android:name=".{YourApplicationClassName}"
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: before call instead of not call.

Answer (score 0):

> In some cases I can see that Activity.onCreate is called before the
>   Appication object gets created (before Application.onCreate is
>   called).

This is not what Android document says about the [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) class. As per the official android documents,

> The Application class, or your subclass of the Application class, is
>   instantiated before any other class when the process for your
>   application/package is created.

Also below is specific explanation of `onCreate()` of an Application class

> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service,
>   or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.

Hence the `onCreate()` of Application has to be invoked 1st and then `onCreate()` of Activity class

So the scenario you have mentioned is not possible as per the flow of instantiation of Application class and Activity class

Comment: I don't understand what you want to express. It doesn't matter when application's onCreate() is invoked. Maybe Android just doesn't wait for it to finish and goes on with the activity. Obviously a bug. I don't care what the documentation says if it doesn't match reality.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are using logging to determine when application is created, check if you are using external logging system, like Timber which is usually instantiated in the end of application `onCreate()`. So it may appear that nothing before this system is instantiated when it is called.

Try to instantiate logging tool before `super.onCreate()` in application `onCreate()`.